# How to get the full-name from this query?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the fullname from the database.
but the data base doesn't have `fullname` but `firstname` `lastname` & `middlename`,
I am new to laravel and i am trying to get the full name like this. but its giving me error

```
 'firstName' => $this->first_name,
 'middleName' => $this->middle_name,
 'lastName' => $this->last_name,
 'fullName' => $this->first_name + $this->middle_name + $this->last_name,
```

Comment: `$this->first_name . $this->middle_name . $this->last_name` use `.` to concat https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#:~:text=The%20first%20is%20the%20concatenation,argument%20on%20the%20left%20side.

Comment: @Daan Today my first day in php. I don't know the terms use in php. I am searching how to merge data :D

Answer (score 2):

easy to search but here you go:

```
$this->first_name .' '. $this->middle_name .' '. $this->last_name,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your model.
$user = User::find(1)

$user->fullName = $user->first_name.' '.$user->middle_name.' '.$user->lastName;